# Merging separate works in wordpress

Tags: localhost, customization

I am caught up in some scenario. Actually my team is working on developing a site using wordpress. They will be working on their machines(localhost) and preparing the pages that come under their share of work. Finally I have to merge those pages into a single site. How can i do that.

Thanks in advance

Pranay Lasod

Comment: **This is a bad idea**. You should setup a shared development site where the content is created and give each team member access to it. The team can work on their local to develop code and update the development site, but even that will be a bigger challenge if you don't use GIT or SVN to manage the code merging...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wordpress Exporter and Importer under the Tools menu in Wordpress to have each person export their content to XML files and you can import each of the exported files.

Know that the export/importer will merge the posts, but post_ids will get changed.

Comment: That might break internal links.